# parsing £ in Perl on a Mac

Tags: regex, macos, perl, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to parse a line containing a UK currency £ symbol using perl on a Mac running El Capitan but can't get it to parse. Ideally I would like to use it split a string

`@Line=split("£",$Hit);`

but I can't even get regular expressions to work. Escaping does not work Is this a Mac character set problem? Listing on the terminal shows a ? in place of the £.

The target text comes from named anchors in HTML written by Seamonkey's Composer:

`<a name="word1£word2">`

Comment: So you're reading this from a file? What is the encoding of the file?

Comment: Western (ISO Latin 1)  but there is also some Russian text

Comment: If you're reading HTML, you should most probably use an HTML parser. Also, it's definitely not possible for a file to be in ISO-Latin-1 and contain Russian (Cyrillic) text, unless it uses character entities. So, again, what is the encoding of the file?

Comment: Seamonkey says windows-1252 but don't know how to read encoding on the mac. Now got Unicode to work in Perl (see below) but strange did not work directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use utf8 pragma as that symbol is unicode character. here is the sample code.

```
use strict;

use utf8;

my $str = qq~<a name="word1£word2">~;
my ($first, $second) = split("£", $str);

print "$first  $second\n";
```

Comment: That works and is more readable than giving `£` as `\N{U+00A3}`!

Answer (score 1):

One simple answer would be

```
@Line=split("\N{U+00A3}",$Hit);
```

where `\N{U+00A3}` is the Unicode for `£`.